# Is there any tips or research of Deep learning for data integration, and label unmatched in train, and test data?

Tags: neural-networks

I am building DL model that test data can have some different labels compared to training dataset. My semi-supervised model is kind of terrible to predict test data, and I want to know is there any DL paper about this kind of work?

And

I'm trying to train with multiple datasets that have common labels but also have other labels as a training set. these datasets have common features but also have other features too.

Is there any tip or guide for pre-process these kind of work? Some Deep learning paper, or some guides?